# ProgrammingError in inserting blob object in MySql using Python

Tags: exception, unicode, python-2.7, mysql-python

I have a MySQL database and a table with the schema

```
tweet_id BIGINT
tweet_metadata LONGBLOB
```

I am trying to insert a row into my database as follows :

```
import MySQLdb as mysql

host = 'localhost'
user = 'root'
passwd = '************'
db = 'twitter'



insert_tweet_query = ''' INSERT INTO tweets(tweet_id, tweet_metadata) VALUES(%s, %s)'''

''' Creates a MySQL connection and returns the cursor '''
def create_connection():
    connection = mysql.connect(host, user, passwd, db,use_unicode=True)
    connection.set_character_set('utf8')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
    cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
    cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')    
    return connection, cursor


''' Close the connection '''
def close_connection(cursor, connection):
    cursor.close()
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()


connection, cursor = create_connection()    
tweet = dict({u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'RT @HMV_Anime: \u7530\u6751\u3086\u304b\u308a\u59eb\u30d9\u30b9\u30c8\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0\u30e0\u300cEverlasting Gift\u300d\u98db\u3076\u3088\u3046\u306b\u58f2\u308c\u3066\u3044\u307e\u3059\uff01\u6728\u66dc\u306f\u6a2a\u30a2\u30ea\u516c\u6f14\uff01\u300c\u30d1\u30fc\u30c6\u30a3\u30fc\u306f\u7d42\u308f\u3089\u306a\u3044\u300d\u306e\u30e9\u30c3\u30d7\u30d1\u30fc\u30c8\u306e\u4e88\u7fd2\u5fa9\u7fd2\u306b\u3082\u5fc5\u9808\u3067\u3059\uff01 http://t.co/SVWm2E1r http://t.co/rSP ...', u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 258550064480387072L, u'source': u'<a href="http://shootingstar067.com/" rel="nofollow">ShootingStar</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'entities': {u'user_mentions': [{u'indices': [3, 13], u'id': 147791077, u'id_str': u'147791077', u'screen_name': u'HMV_Anime', u'name': u'HMV\u30a2\u30cb\u30e1\uff01'}], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': [{u'indices': [100, 120], u'url': u'http://t.co/SVWm2E1r', u'expanded_url': u'http://ow.ly/evEvT', u'display_url': u'ow.ly/evEvT'}, {u'indices': [121, 136], u'url': u'http://t.co/rSP', u'expanded_url': u'http://t.co/rSP', u'display_url': u't.co/rSP'}]}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'retweet_count': 40, u'id_str': u'258550064480387072', u'favorited': False, u'retweeted_status': {u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'\u7530\u6751\u3086\u304b\u308a\u59eb\u30d9\u30b9\u30c8\u30a2\u30eb\u30d0\u30e0\u300cEverlasting Gift\u300d\u98db\u3076\u3088\u3046\u306b\u58f2\u308c\u3066\u3044\u307e\u3059\uff01\u6728\u66dc\u306f\u6a2a\u30a2\u30ea\u516c\u6f14\uff01\u300c\u30d1\u30fc\u30c6\u30a3\u30fc\u306f\u7d42\u308f\u3089\u306a\u3044\u300d\u306e\u30e9\u30c3\u30d7\u30d1\u30fc\u30c8\u306e\u4e88\u7fd2\u5fa9\u7fd2\u306b\u3082\u5fc5\u9808\u3067\u3059\uff01 http://t.co/SVWm2E1r http://t.co/rSPYm0bE #yukarin', u'in_reply_to_status_id': None, u'id': 258160273171574784L, u'source': u'<a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">HootSuite</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'entities': {u'user_mentions': [], u'hashtags': [{u'indices': [127, 135], u'text': u'yukarin'}], u'urls': [{u'indices': [85, 105], u'url': u'http://t.co/SVWm2E1r', u'expanded_url': u'http://ow.ly/evEvT', u'display_url': u'ow.ly/evEvT'}, {u'indices': [106, 126], u'url': u'http://t.co/rSPYm0bE', u'expanded_url': u'http://twitpic.com/awuzz0', u'display_url': u'twitpic.com/awuzz0'}]}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id': None, u'retweet_count': 40, u'id_str': u'258160273171574784', u'favorited': False, u'user': {u'follow_request_sent': None, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'id': 147791077, u'verified': False, u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2573283223/mn4nu924bnxh643sgu1p_normal.jpeg', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'DDEEF6', u'geo_enabled': False, u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'followers_count': 17108, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'C0DEED', u'location': u'\u4e03\u68ee\u4e2d\u5b66\u6821', u'default_profile_image': False, u'listed_count': 1012, u'utc_offset': 32400, u'statuses_count': 33277, u'description': u'\u79c1\u3001\u8d64\u5ea7\u3042\u304b\u308a\u3002\u3069\u3053\u306b\u3067\u3082\u3044\u308b\u3054\u304f\u666e\u901a\u306e\u4e2d\u5b66\u751f\u3002\u305d\u3093\u306a\u79c1\u3060\u3051\u3069\u3001\u6bce\u65e5\u3068\u3063\u3066\u3082\u5145\u5b9f\u3057\u3066\u308b\u306e\u3002\u3060\u3063\u3066\u3042\u304b\u308a\u306f\u2026\u2026 \u3060\u3063\u3066\u3042\u304b\u308a\u306f\u2026\u2026\u3000\uff08\u203b\u3053\u3061\u3089\u306f@HMV_Japan\u306e\u59c9\u59b9\u30a2\u30ab\u30a6\u30f3\u30c8\u3067\u3059\u3002\u3054\u8cea\u554f\u30fb\u304a\u554f\u3044\u5408\u308f\u305b\u306f\u3001HMV\u30b5\u30a4\u30c8\u4e0a\u306e\u5c02\u7528\u30d5\u30a9\u30fc\u30e0\u3088\u308a\u304a\u9858\u3044\u81f4\u3057\u307e\u3059\u3002\uff09', u'friends_count': 17046, u'profile_link_color': u'0084B4', u'profile_image_url': u'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2573283223/mn4nu924bnxh643sgu1p_normal.jpeg', u'following': None, u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/104844943/bg_hmv2.gif', u'profile_background_color': u'202020', u'id_str': u'147791077', u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/104844943/bg_hmv2.gif', u'name': u'HMV\u30a2\u30cb\u30e1\uff01', u'lang': u'ja', u'profile_background_tile': False, u'favourites_count': 0, u'screen_name': u'HMV_Anime', u'notifications': None, u'url': u'http://www.hmv.co.jp/anime/', u'created_at': u'Tue May 25 02:07:35 +0000 2010', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': u'Tokyo', u'protected': False, u'default_profile': False, u'is_translator': False}, u'geo': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'possibly_sensitive': False, u'created_at': u'Tue Oct 16 10:59:40 +0000 2012', u'possibly_sensitive_editable': True, u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': None}, u'user': {u'follow_request_sent': None, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'id': 500471418, u'verified': False, u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2722246932/b71d269b9e1e16f59698b4f7fa23a0fe_normal.jpeg', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'DDEEF6', u'geo_enabled': False, u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'followers_count': 2241, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'C0DEED', u'location': u'\u3072\u3060\u307e\u308a\u8358204\u53f7\u5ba4', u'default_profile_image': False, u'listed_count': 41, u'utc_offset': 32400, u'statuses_count': 18879, u'description': u'\u611f\u3058\u308d\u2026\u2026\u3002 \u2514(\u2510L \u309c\u03c9\u3002)\u2518\u305d\u3057\u3066\uff71\uff8d\u9854\uff80\uff9e\uff8c\uff9e\uff99\uff8b\uff9f\uff70\uff7d\u3060 \u270c( \u055e\u0a0a \u055e)\u270c \u2026\u2026\uff01 \u3051\u3044\u304a\u3093\u3001\u307e\u3069\u30de\u30ae\u3001AB\u3001\u3089\u304d\u2606\u3059\u305f\u3001\u3086\u308b\u3086\u308a\u3001\u30df\u30eb\u30ad\u30a3\u3068\u304b\u306e\u30a2\u30cb\u30e1\u3001\u6771\u65b9\u3001\u30dc\u30ab\u30ed\u597d\u304d\u3060\u3088\u2517(^\u03c9^ )\u251b\u30c7\u30c7\u30f3\uff01 \u30d5\u30a9\u30ed\u30d0\u306f\u3059\u308b\u304b\u3089\u5f85\u3063\u3068\u3044\u3066 \u53ef\u6190\u3061\u3083\u3093\u540c\u76dfNo.9 \u308c\u3044\u3080\u540c\u76dfNo.4 \u898f\u5236\u57a2\u2192@SpeedPer_2', u'friends_count': 2038, u'profile_link_color': u'0084B4', u'profile_image_url': u'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2722246932/b71d269b9e1e16f59698b4f7fa23a0fe_normal.jpeg', u'following': None, u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/600710368/ff2z5gv4s83u313432hj.jpeg', u'profile_background_color': u'C0DEED', u'id_str': u'500471418', u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/600710368/ff2z5gv4s83u313432hj.jpeg', u'name': u'\u3055\u30fc\u3057\u3083\u3059@\u30cf\u30cb\u30ab\u30e0\u30ac\u30c1\u52e2', u'lang': u'ja', u'profile_background_tile': True, u'favourites_count': 3066, u'screen_name': u'SpeedPer', u'notifications': None, u'url': u'https://mobile.twitter.com/account', u'created_at': u'Thu Feb 23 05:10:57 +0000 2012', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': u'Irkutsk', u'protected': False, u'default_profile': False, u'is_translator': False}, u'geo': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': None, u'possibly_sensitive': False, u'created_at': u'Wed Oct 17 12:48:33 +0000 2012', u'possibly_sensitive_editable': True, u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': None, u'place': None})



cursor.execute(insert_tweet_query, (tweet['id_str'], tweet))


close_connection(cursor, connection)
```

However, despite setting appropriate 'UTF-8' encodings I get an exception as follows

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \': \'NULL\', u\'truncated\': \'0\', u\'text\': "\'RT @HMV_Anime: \\xe7\\x94\\xb0\\xe6\\x9d\\x91\\\' at line 1')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try with *repr*:

```
cursor.execute(insert_tweet_query, (tweet['id_str'], repr(tweet)))
```